# Is possible to make a gtk window transparent on Microsoft Windows?

Tags: gtk, pygtk

I'm using pygtk to make an application need transparent window, it's should works on Linux and Windows.

I use `set_colormap` to set a `rgba_colormap` I retrieve from `gtk.Screen().get_rgba_colormap()` to set window transprent.

But Windows doesn't support `rgba_colormap`, so I cannot get `rgba_colormap` on Windows.

Is possible to make a gtk window transparent in other way?

Answer (score 0):

No. You need an rgba colormap, and as you found out, this is not supported by gtk2 on windows.